# Can the structure of an element given for xsd:any be validated?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I stumbled upon this [w3schools entry](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_complex_any.asp) about xsd:any (please don't comment on using w3schools as reference in general, this question is about whether w3schools is right in this particular case). It basically describes that you have this element as base (in some schema `family.xsd`):

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And then, you define an additional schema `children.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="children">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="childname" type="xs:string"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now they say that based on those schemas, you can write this document which will be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.microsoft.com family.xsd
                             https://www.w3schools.com children.xsd">
  <person>
    <firstname>Hege</firstname>
    <lastname>Refsnes</lastname>
    <children>
      <childname>Cecilie</childname>
    </children>
  </person>
  <!-- ... -->
</persons>
```

Assuming that the surrounding structure, whose definition is not shown, is valid, my question is: Can and will a Validator actually check for the proper structure of the `<children>` element here, and if so, how?

My understanding is that the second schema defines a document whose root is a `<children>` element. However, XSD does not provide a direct mapping from element name to type, since elements with the same name in different scopes may have different types (right?). So as I see it, a validator cannot know that the `<children>` element given inside `<person>` should actually be validated according to the definition in the second schema. Therefore, the second schema is useless here and the document would be valid even if `<children>` contained some element `<foo/>`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `processContents="strict"` attribute on the `xs:any` says that the element that appears here must have a global element declaration, and must be valid against that declaration. There can only be one global element declaration for any given element name (a global declaration is one appearing as a child of `xs:schema`).

In your case the document is not valid, because of namespaces. The target namespace for your `children.xsd` schema document is `https://www.w3schools.com`, but the `children` element in the instance is in namespace `http://www.microsoft.com`. So the validator should report that no global element declaration for `children` was found.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution

1) Update your xsd with:

```
<xs:any minOccurs="0" processContents="strict"/>
```

This will prevent the validator from accepting whathever "any" xml.

2) Design a super schema being the union of all existing schemas, and use this super schema as input of the Validator.

For instance (in Java):

```
Source xmlSource = // the xml to validate;
Source schemaSource = // your super xsd
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(xmlSource);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but a) I did not ask for a *solution* but rather about how the validation process works, and b) `processContents="strict"` is the default, so explicitly specifying it should not make any difference, should it?